# JS Скачать файл в ANSI-кодировке (Windows-1251)

Tags: javascript, html, utf-8, href, cp1251

Много вопросов было уже типа: "*открываю файл с помощью `<input type="file"/>` и `FileReader`, а там значки ����� вместо русских букв*"

Решение такого понятно:

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsText(file, 'CP1251');
```

**А КАК СДЕЛАТЬ НАОБОРОТ?**

То есть

Есть текст на странице

Скачиваю его с помощью ссылки `href="data:text/plain;charset:CP1251,ТЕКСТ_ДЛЯ_СКАЧИВАНИЯ"`

Вот как нужно этот текст закодировать, чтобы он скачивался, а потом при его открытии бы "возникали значки ����� вместо русских букв"?

Ну и чтобы, естественно, его можно было бы декодировать потом нормально

Пример нужного скачиваемого файла с нужной кодировкой: [файл](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1zCuw6zfMTq_2pDZL6Fif6LcqiXTu9EyC)

Пробовал делать так, используя эту библиотеку: [windows-1251](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/windows-1251)

```
var text = 'ТЕКСТ_ДЛЯ_СКАЧИВАНИЯ';    
a.setAttribute("href", "data:text/plain;charset:CP1251," + windows1251.encode(text));
```

- Не помогло

Comment: я никогда так не делал, но я бы попробовал тут `"data:text/plain;charset:CP1251,"` сменить кодировку на что-то другое, на дос какойнить к примеру или на утф

Comment: @RostyslavKuzmovych , charset тут не особо поможет, поскольку это всего лишь мета-тег, должна быть закодирована сама строка: http://programmerbook.ru/html/common-values/url/protocol/data/

Comment: @RostyslavKuzmovych, больше мыслей нет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел рабочий пример со словом `привет`

```
var a = document.createElement("a");
a.setAttribute("href", "data:text/plain;charset=cp1251,%EF%F0%E8%E2%E5%F2");
a.setAttribute("download", "Test.txt");
a.click();
```

И функцию, которая это слово декодирует

```
function decodeCP1251(string){
    function decodeChar(s, p) {
        var cp1251 = 'ЂЃ‚ѓ„…†‡€‰Љ‹ЊЌЋЏђ‘’“”•–—�™љ›њќћџ ЎўЈ¤Ґ¦§Ё©Є«¬*®Ї°±Ііґµ¶·\
ё№є»јЅѕїАБВГДЕЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯабвгдежзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя';
        p = parseInt(p, 16);
        return p < 128 ? String.fromCharCode(p) : cp1251[p - 128];
    }
    var str = string;
    return str.replace(/%(..)/g,decodeChar);
}
```

Ну и судя по ней, кодирующая функция может выглядеть вот так

```
var encodeCP1251 = function (string) {
    function encodeChar(c) {
        var isKyr = function (str) {
            return /[а-я]/i.test(str);
        }
        var cp1251 = 'ЂЃ‚ѓ„…†‡€‰Љ‹ЊЌЋЏђ‘’“”•–—�™љ›њќћџ ЎўЈ¤Ґ¦§Ё©Є«¬*®Ї°±Ііґµ¶·\
ё№є»јЅѕїАБВГДЕЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯабвгдежзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя'; 
        var p = isKyr(c) ? (cp1251.indexOf(c) + 128) : c.charCodeAt(0);
        var h = p.toString(16);
        if (h=='a'){
            h = '0A';
        }
        return '%' + h;
    }
    var res = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) { 
        res += encodeChar(string.charAt(i)) //ну или string[i]
    }
    return res;
}
```

Переменная `cp1251` **ИМЕННО ТАКАЯ, КАК НАПИСАНО, С ТАКИМ ЖЕ ПЕРЕНОСОМ И Т.П.**

Овнокодно, но работает)

```
var a = document.createElement("a");
a.setAttribute("href", "data:text/plain;charset=CP1251," + encodeCP1251('НУЖНЫЙ РУССКИЙ ТЕКСТ'));
a.setAttribute("download", "Test.txt");
a.click();
```

Тема закрыта)